# Observe reference removal

Tags: firebase

I have a very simple question.

I have a reference like this : /myref for which I set a value for example : "Hello"

And I want to listen when the myref reference is removed.

I tried observeSingleEvent Child Removed but it is not triggered as there is no child.
And I don't want to listen the parent reference until the child removed is myref.

Do you have any solution ?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What language/SDK are we working with?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to observe child events, just watch the path itself and look for `NSNull` (which means the path no longer exists):

```
Firebase *postsRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts"];

FEventTypeChildAdded event
// triggered before this point.
[postsRef observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.value == [NSNull null])
     NSLog(@"value was removed");
}];
```

Comment: thank you for your response. However if the value at this ref is changed, your event will be triggered.

Comment: which is why we need to check it for null. Another alternative would be to watch the parent path for child removed events. These are your options.